# Slick Accordion CSS issues on mobile responsiveness

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how I'm able to make this Slick Accordion fully mobile responsive and it seems as if everything is overlapping on everything that I have tried.

Here is the Accordion on Desktop (Works perfectly):

[image]

Here is the Accordion on Mobile Responsiveness on (991px and less):

[image]

So I can't seem to figure out how to make all the things appear inline like the mobile version, I have tried Display/Position/etc.. attributes and have failed miserably.

Here is the code:

```css
#AccordionHeadings {
 font-weight: bolder;
 color: slategrey;
 font-size: medium;
}
.small {
 height: 70px!important;
}
.small:hover {
 background-color: #F8E498!important;
}
.col-md-1 {
 padding: 0px!important;
 margin-top: 5px!important;
}
#AccordionText {
 margin-bottom: 0px!important;
 color: gray;
}
#AccordIcon {
 padding-right: 10px;
 height:25px;
 width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8">
   <h4>Choose the right app for the job!</h4>
   <hr style="margin-top: 10px;"/>
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#s0" data-parent="#accordion" style="background-color: #e5edf4;">
      <img id="AccordIcon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148946.svg" />
      <span id="AccordionHeadings">File Storage and Sharing</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right"></span></a>
      <div id="s0" class="sublinks collapse"> <!-- sublinks collapse -->
         <a class="list-group-item small" href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/OneDrive.aspx">
            <div class="col-md-1">
               <img style="height: 32px; width: 45px;" src="https://i.imgur.com/e0a3j2l.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11">
               <h5>OneDrive</h5>
               <p id="AccordionText">Store your files in one place, share them 
    with others, and get them from any device connected to the 
    Internet.</p>
            </div>
         </a>
         <a class="list-group-item small" href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/SharePointOnline.aspx">
            <div class="col-md-1">
               <img src="https://i.imgur.com/uii8cJt.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11">
               <h5>SharePoint</h5>
               <p id="AccordionText">Share and manage content, knowledge, and 
    applications to empower teamwork and quickly find information 
    within your organization.</p>
            </div>
         </a>
         <a class="list-group-item small" href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/Teams.aspx">
            <div class="col-md-1">
               <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fV0AGNi.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11">
               <h5>Teams</h5>
               <p id="AccordionText">Microsoft Teams is a chat-based workspace 
    offered in Office 365. Teams makes collaborating with your team 
    easy.</p>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have shortened the code down for you so that only one accordion row is visible just so there isn't so much code, and I have also included the proper jQuery libraries and the Bootstrap CDN libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it all figured out, since I had predefined CSS using Sharepoint Master Pages and Bootstrap it was not aligning well, but this solved the issue.

```css
@media (max-width: 992px)
{
 #slick-slide02 {
  display: visible!important;
 }
 .col-md-1 {
  float: left!important;
  margin-right: 10px!important;
 }
 .col-md-1 img {
  height: auto!important;
  width: 45px!important;
 }
 #AccordionText {
  display: flex!important;
 }
 .small {
  height: auto!important;
 }
}

.small {
 height: 70px;
}
```

Simple css changes has fixed the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below given structure of html. Basically add `d-flex align-items-center` on the anchors and keep the `heading` and `p` elements in a div. And add height and widths to your images.

```css
#AccordionHeadings {
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: slategrey;
  font-size: medium;
}
.small:hover {
  background-color: #F8E498!important;
}
.list-group-item h5 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#AccordionText {
  margin-bottom: 0px!important;
  color: gray;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#AccordIcon {
  padding-right: 10px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-md-8">
      <h4>Choose the right app for the job!</h4>
      <hr style="margin-top: 10px;" />
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#s0" data-parent="#accordion" style="background-color: #e5edf4;">
            <img id="AccordIcon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148946.svg" />
            <span id="AccordionHeadings">File Storage and Sharing</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right"></span></a>
          <div id="s0" class="sublinks collapse">
            <!-- sublinks collapse -->
            <a class="list-group-item small d-flex align-items-center" href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/OneDrive.aspx">

              <img class="img-fluid" style="height: 32px; width: 45px;" src="https://i.imgur.com/e0a3j2l.png" />
              <div class="">
                <h5>OneDrive</h5>
                <p id="AccordionText">Store your files in one place, share them with others, and get them from any device connected to the Internet.
                </p>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a class="list-group-item small d-flex align-items-center" href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/SharePointOnline.aspx">

              <img class="img-fluid" style="height: 32px; width: 45px;" src="https://i.imgur.com/uii8cJt.png" />
              <div>
                <h5>SharePoint</h5>
                <p id="AccordionText">Share and manage content, knowledge, and applications to empower teamwork and quickly find information within your organization.</p>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a class="list-group-item small d-flex align-items-center" href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/Teams.aspx">

              <img class="img-fluid" style="height: 32px; width: 45px;" src="https://i.imgur.com/fV0AGNi.png" />
              <div>
                <h5>Teams</h5>
                <p id="AccordionText">Microsoft Teams is a chat-based workspace offered in Office 365. Teams makes collaborating with your team easy.
                </p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked amazing on standalone pages, but with my Masterpages and Bootstrap, it wasn't aligning correctly on my mobile version. I got it to work using some CSS tweaking. I do appreciate the help so much!